# Java lambda expression -- mapping and then modifying a list?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Using a Java 8 lambda expression, I'm trying to do something like this.

```
List<NewObject> objs = ...;
for (OldObject oldObj : oldObjects) {
  NewObject obj = oldObj.toNewObject();
  obj.setOrange(true);
  objs.add(obj);
}
```

I wrote this code.

```
oldObjects.stream()
  .map(old -> old.toNewObject())
  .forEach({new.setOrange("true")})
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is invalid code because I'm then trying to do `.collect()` on what's returned by `.forEach()`, but `forEach` is void and does not return a list.

How should this be structured?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Stream`'s `peek` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-), which returns the `Stream` because it's an intermediate operation.  It normally isn't supposed to have a side effect (it's supposed to be "non-interfering"), but in this case, I think the side effect (`setOrange(true)`) is intended and is fine.

```
List<NewObject> newObjects =
    oldObjects.stream()
        .map(OldObject::toNewObject)
        .peek( n -> n.setOrange(true))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's about as verbose as your non-streams code, so you can choose which technique to use.

Comment: There's a difference between side-effect-free and non-interfering.  (Note that a void-returning lambda can *only* have side-effects, except for the trivial `e -> {}` consumer.)  Determining that the lambda passed to `peek` actually is non-interfering is not always trivial (though what you've got here *looks* harmless enough.)

Comment: it's not more interfering than `peek( n -> print(n) )`

Comment: @bayou.io: this is not correct. Mutating a property of a stream element can be interfering, e.g. if the same element appears multiple times within the same stream. This is different to a `print` operation. But since `oldObj.toNewObject()` seems to create new instances we can conclude that this is not the case here. However, it still would be cleaner to construct the `NewObject` instance and set the `orange` property in one lambda within the `map` operation. Then, `peek` would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `peek`.

```
List<NewObject> list = oldObjects.stream()
                                 .map(OldObject::toNewObject)
                                 .peek(o -> o.setOrange(true))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, you can mutate the elements after forming the list.

```
List<NewObject> list = oldObjects.stream()
                                 .map(OldObject::toNewObject)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.forEach(o -> o.setOrange(true));
```