# When using java streams map function I'm getting insert ";" to complete BlockStatements error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Here is my stream. The status inside of the map function is an enum

```
List<Review> tempList = reviewList.stream()
            .map(x -> x.setStatus(Status.APPROVED))
```

It's not only with the map method. I tried other methods and got the same error

Comment: Is that the entire statement? It needs to end with a semicolon (`;`), like all statements in Java.

Comment: In addition to the syntax problems you are having, you have (at least) two other serious problems here.  The first is there is no terminal operation, so the stream does nothing.  The second is that you should not be using `map` to side-effect the elements.  Instead, use `forEach`, such as `reviewList().stream().forEach(x -> x.setStatus(status))`.

Comment: I suppose it wouldn’t even compile with the semicolon, since `map` would return a `Stream`, not a `List`

Comment: @BrianGoetz What about using `peek()` to modify the stream elements as they're passing through? Is that discouraged?

Comment: @shmosel It's a compile error, and not specific to streams. All statements have to be terminated.

Comment: @user207421 If so, this question should be closed as typo. I have a feeling the real question is about using streams correctly. But I didn't mean to undo your edit; feel free to revert.

Comment: @shmosel I have already so voted.

Comment: @shmosel `peek` is provided only for debugging (note the name, it connotes a sneaky look) and is not guaranteed to be called in all cases.  Use `forEach` for side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement does not end with a semi-colon nor is it complete.  You need a terminal operation to start the stream. You would not really return a new list but just setting the status on the original one. And even if you did return a list you are still setting the original objects.  You would need to copy the object for each review.

To just set the status on the original object do

```
reviewList.forEach(r->r.setStatus(Status.APPROVED));
```

or

```
for (Review r : reviewList) {
      r.setStatus(Status.APPROVED);
}
```

To do what you want you would need to create a new list. You could do the following although with some creativity it could be shorter.  You would need to write a `copyOf` method so you aren't changing the same object.

```
List<Review> tempList = reviewList.stream()
        .map(r-> {
               Review rev = copyOf(r);
               rev.setStatus(Status.APPROVED);
               return rev;
         })
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method, whether it will work as you expected; Hope to help you

```
List<Review> tempList = reviewList.stream()
            .map(x -> {
                x.setStatus(Status.APPROVED)
                return x;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if you're just setting state, I suggest you use a for loop or foreach, as others have said;